# A problem about filters and ultrafilters

Tags: set-theory, filters

Let $a$ be an ultrafilter on a set $\mho$. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be an $a$-indexed
family of filters (that is $\mathcal{L}$ is a function from $a$ to the set of
filters on $\mho$).

Are the following two logical formulas equivalent?

1. $\forall L \in \mho^a : ( ( \forall i \in a : L_i \in \mathcal{L}_i)
   \Rightarrow \exists A \in a \forall i \in a : A \subseteq L_i)$;
2. $\forall i \in a : a \supseteq \mathcal{L}_i$.

Comment: 2 does not imply 1 because $\mathrm{id}\in\mho^\alpha$. Let $\alpha$ be a non-principle ultrafilter and $\mathcal{L}(i)$ to be the elements above or equal to $i$. Then 2 is true while 1 is not: in the case of $L=\mathrm{id}$, the antecedent is obviously true while the consequent is false because $a$ is non-principle

Comment: An other similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735366/an-other-question-about-filter-and-ultrafilters

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have found a counterexample (please check me).

Let $\mho=\mathbb{R}$.

Let $\Delta_+$ be the filter on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by the base $(0;\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon>0$.

Let $a$ be an ultrafilter containing in $\Delta_+$.

Take all $\mathcal{L}=\Delta_+$.

We can take $L_i=(0;\epsilon)$ for arbitrarily small epsilons.

The this is a counterexample: the formula (2) obviously true and (1) is false because $A$ must be contained in every interval $(0;\epsilon)$ what is impossible.