# An other question about filters and ultrafilters

Tags: set-theory, filters

Let $a$ be an ultrafilter on a set $\mho$. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be an $a$-indexed
family of filters (that is $\mathcal{L}$ is a function from $a$ to the set of
filters on $\mho$).

Conjecture: For every nontrivial ultrafilter $a$ (2) does not follow from (1):

1. $\forall L \in \mho^a : ( ( \forall i \in a : L_i \in \mathcal{L}_i)
   \Rightarrow a \supseteq [L_i]_{i \in a})$ (where $[L_i]_{i \in a}$ is the filter generated by the family $L$ of sets);
2. $\forall L \in \mho^a : ( ( \forall i \in a : L_i \in \mathcal{L}_i)
   \Rightarrow \exists A \in a \forall i \in n : A \subseteq L_i)$.

Comment: this is obviously not true. For example if $\mathcal{L}$ is a constant function to a principal subfilter of $a$, then both 1 and 2 are true.

Comment: @Apostolos: I mean that is not implied for every $\mathcal{L}$